# Mythic Racial Ability

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, monsters, racial-traits, mythic-adventures

In PathFinder-1e by RAW, a Devil with [See In Darkness (Su)](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/devil/), who also has levels in a mythic class, still seems to be hindered by a mythic [darkness](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/darkness/) spell.

**Is there a way to be able to make race or class abilities mythic?**

(If it can be done, I assume the description for the mythic ability would have to explicitly call out the way it interacts with other abilities and spells.)

It just seems unbalanced that an ability which counters a spell cannot be raised to counter its mythic variant. Especially so if the ability user and the caster are the same person. Now a Devil Mythic Archmage can't see unhindered in their own darkness!

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether or not the See in Darkness ability is Mythic level or not - it's the definition of the Mythic version of Darkness that stops it from working. Are you actually really wanting a generic way to make any ability Mythic, or wanting a generic way to work around Mythic abilities?

Comment: @YugoZuno You're right my question is off target. Edit coming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There isn't a supernatural ability mythic power enhancer.**

Sadly, supernatural abilities haven't been extensively considered by the creator, so there isn't a canon ability which does this.

If you wanted to homebrew one, an ability like this would probably work.

> Mythic Magic (Su)

> Up to three times per day, when the creature casts a spell, it can cast the mythic version instead (as with all mythic spells, the creature must expend mythic power to cast a mythic spell in this way).

> Format: mythic magic 3/day; Location: Special Attacks.

Just replace mythic magic with mythic see in darkness. Up to three times per day, they can use a chosen supernatural ability in a mythic way.

Comment: I was with you up until the homebrew sample, and then things went awry. You've given a way to do the mythic darkness spell not to counter it!
Considering the Mythic Deepsight Feat exists, perhaps the homebrew addition of a Mythic "See In Darkness" Feat would be the simplest resolution to the issue. I think that would work with existing mechanics smoothly enough. Thanks for the clear answer to my question, and pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I tweaked it to meet your question better.

Comment: Thanks Nepene-Nep, though it is "See In Darkness" not "See Through Darkness" (just sticking to specifics ;) ). If I'm going to homebrew a Mythic Feat then I'd use an existing one as a base, Mythic Deepsight has no 'times per day' so I don't think Mythic See In Darkness should either as it seems unduly limiting.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.